# urlseen text in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to remove (urlseen) text from bibliography.

[image]

And von neumann item's date not shown on bibliography.

My bib file :

```
@article{johnvonneumann1945,
author = {{Von Neumann}, John},
title = {{First Draft of a Report on the EDVAC}},
url = {http://www.virtualtravelog.net/wp/wp-content/media/2003-08-TheFirstDraft.pdf},
date = {1945-10-08},
urldate = {2017-10-08},
Addendum   = {[Erişim Tarihi : 08-10-2017]},
}

@article{guye.blellochvebrucem.maggs2017,
author = {Blelloch, Guy E and Maggs, Bruce M},
title = {{Parallel Algorithms}},
url = {http://www.cs.cmu.edu/{~}guyb/papers/BM04.pdf},
urldate = {2017-10-08},
Addendum   = {[Erişim Tarihi : 08-10-2017]},
}
```

Biblatex codes:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace ve\space}%and yerine ve koyması için
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space} %isimle yıl arası virgül için

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers={\space vd. \space}}      %et al yerine vd koyması için
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace ve\space}                 %and yerine ve koyması için
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers={\space vd. \space}}      %et al yerine vd koyması için
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Add to your preamble : `\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{#1}`.

Comment: Thank you it worked :)
Do you have an idea what is the problem with von neumann date. Always show empty paranthesis.

Comment: Could you post a   minimal code showing the problem? Normally, it shouldn't with what you've added, so there must be something else.

Comment: I deleted date = {1945-10-08}, and it's fixed. Thank You :)

Comment: @Bernard Do you want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default formatting of the  `urldate` field is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
```

Just replace it in your preamble with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{#1}
```